# Google Maps API Python/R

Tags: python, r, google-maps

I am trying to use the google maps API for [nearby](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) search and ideally I'd use a [latlngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object for my search. I have been using R but can do python as well and seem to run into the same issue. It's working fine with the point/radius but I'd like to set a bounding box if possible. It seems that for javascript you can input a latlngBounds object but maybe not if you're using the python or R api? Does anyone have any knowledge on if this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't give it a LatLngBounds object. I'd like to give it parameters for the southwest and northeast corners but I can't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've alluded to, the Javascript API allows you to use a LatLngBounds object, however, the [web services API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) does not.

A couple of options I can suggest

1. Write some Javascript and parse it yourself in R using something like [`library(V8)`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/index.html), or your own [html widget](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlwidgets/index.html)
2. Also in R, use my [googleway](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/NEWS.md) package, and in particular the `google_palces()` function to do a [nearby serach](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search).

---

```
library(googleway)

## you need an API key
key <- read.dcf("~/Documents/.googleAPI", fields = "GOOGLE_API_KEY")

res <- google_places(search_string = "cafe", 
                     location = c(-37.8203155,144.9800428), 
                     radius = 2000, 
                     key = key)

# res$results$name
# [1] "Café Vue"                                              "Switch Board Cafe"                                     "The Journal Cafe"                                     
# [4] "Krimper Cafe"                                          "65 Degrees Cafe"                                       "Basement Cafe"                                        
# [7] "Cafe Domain"                                           "Druids Cafe"                                           "Cafe Kinetic"                                         
# [10] "Paris End Cafe & Catering Melbourne 20 Collins street" "Mothership Cafe"                                       "THE J Walk Cafe"                                      
# [13] "Richmond Rush Cafe"                                    "Bullrun café"                                          "Crossroads Cafe"                                      
# [16] "Espresso Cafe Richmond"                                "8 Miles Cafe & Convenience Store"                      "Cafe Bar Mile"                                        
# [19] "The Industrial Cafe"                                   "Park Lane Cafe"
```